# gapi.client.getToken() always return null when refresh ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

So I am making a React app that accesses the user's Google calendar and fetch their events.

It is working fine, but the problem is that when I refresh the app, the user has to consent again, which I would like to avoid.

Is there a way for me to skip the consent, after the first time the user consent already?

On user click to log in

```
function handleAuthClick() { 
    tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
      if (resp.error !== undefined) {
        throw (resp);
      }
    };

  if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
    // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
    // when establishing a new session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent', access_type:"offline"});
  } else {
    // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
    tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
  }
}
```

Some other function that is used to log in that I copy from google's documentation

```
function gapiLoaded() {
    try{
      gapi.load('client', intializeGapiClient);
    } catch {
      console.log("Not Logged in");
    }
}

/**
* Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
* discovery doc to initialize the API.
*/
async function intializeGapiClient() {
  var API_KEY = "x";

  fetch("http://localhost:5050/id").then(resp => {
  // fetch("https://calendar-342103.uc.r.appspot.com/id").then(resp => {
    return resp.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    API_KEY = data.val2;
  }).then(async () => {
    try{
      await gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
      });
      gapiInited = true;
      maybeEnableButtons();
    } catch {
      console.log("User not logged in")
    }
  })
}

/**
* Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
*/
function gisLoaded() {
  var CLIENT_ID = "x";

  fetch("http://localhost:5050/id").then(resp => {
  // fetch("https://calendar-342103.uc.r.appspot.com/id").then(resp => {
    return resp.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    CLIENT_ID = data.val1;
  }).then(() => {
    try {
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES,
      callback: '', // defined later
      });
      gisInited = true;
      maybeEnableButtons();
    } catch {
  
    }
  })
}
```